# How to check a 3x2 rectangle box in a sudoku 6x6;

Tags: java, sudoku

(SOLVED)
I'm trying to make a 6x6 sudoku in java grapichs, but i have some problem in checking the 3x2 boxes, i've attempted something but it's only for 9x9 sudoku.
This method check in a sudoku grid 9x9 if the in the 3x3 boxes there is already the number in input. If there isn't it will return true, else false.

## Rules of the sudoku:

1. No duplicate number in each rows
2. No duplicate number in each columns
3. no duplicate number in each boxes

---

```
private boolean isInBox(int row, int col, int number) {
    int r = row - row % 3;               //check the row a group of three
    int c = col - col % 3;               //Check the column a group of three
    //cycle the boxes
    for (int i = r; i < r + 3; i++){
        for (int j = c; j < c + 3; j++){
            if (solution_grid[i][j] == number){
                return false; // if the number exist in the box it will exit with a negative response
            }
        }
    }
    return true;  //if everything goes right it will give a positive response
}
```

---

Example of a 6x6 sudoku with boxes

```
 0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0
-------------
 0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0
-------------
 0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0
```

Comment: No it work, but only for 9x9 grid, i need to adjust it so that it will work for 6x6 grid

Comment: You already said that. Again: what is the purpose of that method? Please read [mcve] and tell us what you expect the method to do, and what it actually does.

Comment: Sorry, this method in a grid 9x9 lets you check in 3x3 boxes if all the numbers are different

Comment: I think the problem here is that you understand what you are talking about because you know the difference between 9x9 and 6x6 suduko. I know that I do not know the difference, maybe others do not as well. So you need to explain the differences that you are trying to achieve. the minimal, complete verifiable example means providing some information (e.g. how is the grid laid out, some sample data / scenarios and what do you expect the function to produce for those difference scenarios?

Comment: The method is agnostic to the size of the matrix, so 9x9 or 6x6, it doesn't matter. The difference is the size of the box, 3x3 Vs 3x2 in your app. To fix it you just need to change the second line to `c = col - col % 2` and the second `for` to `j < c + 2`, but what you really need is to debug this method and understand how it works

Comment: @matanper thanks for your solution, i applied it and now all runs smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically that method uses the modulo operator to compute the number of rows and columns. Then it compares all elements in the "solution" array against the given number.

One can use that method to determine whether all numbers are different (by running that method in a loop again for all numbers). Which is terrible inefficient.

Instead: create a map. As keys, use all potential numbers (1 to 9 for the small Sudoku for example). The value is boolean, and false. Then iterate the solution once. For each number you find in the solution, check if the corresponding map value is false. If so, change it to true. If you find a value that is already true, you know that this number is showing up at least twice in your solution.

Note: nothing in my answer talks about the size of the Sudoku grid. So just go and adapt it to the "sizes" and numbers you will need for 6 X 6.